# Generate a file and deploy it to image, inside a yocto recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I need to generate some kind of manifest, based on the contents of the recipe. This file needs to be deployed to the image as well.

To generate a file, I have seen in many *bbclasses* that python code functions are used in a similar way such as:

```py
      python do_create_manifest () {
          [...]
          filename = d.expand("${D}${LOC}/${MANIFEST_NAME}")
          [...]
          with open (filename,'w') as manifest_file:
             json.dump(manifest_dict, manifest_file, indent=True)
          os.chmod(filename, 0o644)
      }
```

- Is there any other preferred way?

The file is created after adding the task dependency, however when such file is packaged, the **host-user-contaminated** warning arises in the file.

Despite I have seen in many recipes the use of:

```
        chown -R root:root ${D}${...}/${...}
```

This fails, as chown needs to be run by root, and bitbake is ran by current user:

```
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_uncontaminate
| chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/thud/build-r0w/[...]/manifest.json': Operation not permitted
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

- How would I fix the **host-user-contaminated** warning in this case?

---

**Note:** I know this would prevent the warning from appearing, but not solving the problem.

```
    INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "host-user-contaminated"
```

Comment: Could you share the complete recipe? (As well as the complete error log).

Comment: Hello @danlor the code is inside a class and the recipe is too long to add in this question. I have added the given error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify where this file gets created, what path `filename` contains, but from the error I suspect you create it directly under `${D}` somewhere.

If you instead create the manifest file under e.g. `${B}`, and then during the regular `do_install` you install it using e.g. `install -Dm0644 ${B}/my_manifest ${D}/dest/path/my_manifest` the ownership issue will be taken care of as with any other file that a recipe installs.

Just make sure that the do_create_manifest task is run before do_install.

Comment: Exactly, this solved the problem. I have completed a bit the question to clarify your first assumption, I was in fact placing the file in ${D}. 
Would not it be more correct to place it in ${B}?

Comment: @urnenfeld Yes ${B} is probably more appropriate, but I don't think it has a practical effects in this case. I've updated the reply.